# android best way to save very tiny data on device

Tags: java, android, firebase

in my application launching activity i need to check three things every time app is started

1. App Version
2. is User Login
3. is User Account Created

I am using **Firebase** for database so every time when use start app i check in DB on **Datachange** and then send user to activity according return results and case area like below:

```
//check if newer version is available (Step 1)
if (appVersionMatch) {
    CheckLogin();
} else {
    //Take user to appstore for app update
}


// (Step 2)
public void CheckLogin() {
    if (userLogin) {
        CheckUserExist()
    } else {
        //Show user Login activity
    }
}


// (Step 3)
public void CheckUserExist() {
    if (user.exist()) {
        //Go To main Activity
    } else {
        //Go To Register activity
    }
}
```

and this flow works fine but it always take some time to check all these three thing..i was thinking if i could save on first login and on account create info so there is no need to check it again so user can go to main activity faster i tried do it with  following but is not work as expected:

```
 SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    editor = pref.edit();
                    boolean isLoogenIn = pref.getBoolean("userLoginCheck", false);
```

Comment: what problem are you experience with SharedPreferences? Is only a timing issue?

Comment: yes after saving data its still take time on this activity

Comment: And are you sure the delay is due to SharedPref? I suspect it could be another issue like some Google initialization. For example, if you have a map on you nexr activty it will take some time to load (a couple of seconds). Maybe using some logging you can track down the problem. It's unlikely that SharedPref is taking too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I would do it using `SharedPreferences`.

First create a separate class( I use it to save other informations like url, constants etc.) In that create a `SharedPreferences`.

```
public class project_constants {
private static String PREF_NAME = "project_pref";

private static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public static boolean getUserLogin(Context context) {
    return getPrefs(context).getBoolean("login", false);
}

public static void setUserLogin(Context context, boolean input) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPrefs(context).edit();
    editor.putBoolean("login", input);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Now when the user log's in, you should use `project_constants.setuserLogin(getApplicationContext,True);`.

Now when you want to check whether the user has logged in or not, you can use `project_constants.getuserLogin(getApplicationContext);` , if that's true, the user is logged in, else no.

Answer (score 1):

For the first time you should save your data in SharedPreference when data is ready from firebase with:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("userLoginCheck", false);
editor.commit();
```

Then you can get preference value for next times with:

```
 boolean isLoogenIn = pref.getBoolean("userLoginCheck", true);
```

Comment: For the first time you have to wait for getting data from firebase and then for next times, you can check with firebase fast. Share your full code to better help.