# How to get the current userID on fragments, after you logged in

Tags: android, android-fragments

**userLogin.class**

```
try {
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
     if(!obj.getBoolean("error")){
     SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                                        .userLogin(
                                                obj.getInt("id"),
                                                obj.getString("firstname"),
                                                obj.getString("lastname"),
                                                obj.getString("s_id")
                                        );

     startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
```

finish();

```
       }else{

       }
   } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```

This is the code when you are trying to login.
How to put the current `s_id` to other activity like "FragmentActivity".
It should be like this. after you logged in, it will go to `FragmentActivity` also its should get the current user which the `s_id`.
I already put the code

```
Intent intentMainActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                intentMainActivity.putExtra("s_id", username);
                                startActivity(intentMainActivity);
```

But I don't know how to get in `FragmentActivity`, I tried

```
final String userID = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("s_id");
```

I put in below the 
`private void fetchNewsFeedData() {`
but still it doesn't work.
please help me solve this problem.
thank you.

Comment: This should definitely work for you. Use `sharedPreference`, that way you can use the data anywhere you want in the project. Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52203903/3538065

Comment: thanks @driftking9987 i'll try on it

Comment: Does MainActivity start FragmentActivity?

Comment: @SonTruong it start on MainActivity, Then HolderFragment after that there's 3 fragments.

Comment: So your app navigation will be: `LoginActivity -> MainActivity -> FragmentActivity -> 3 fragments inside FragmentActivity`. Is that correct?

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this - store your data into the any kind of storag, pass it over intent or host in runtime memory with access over static instance. From your code it looks like you obtain your intent data not from fragment but from activity, in this way in your activity you should obtain the data and pass it to the fragment when you instantiate it or when obtain the existing instance over fragment manager

Answer (score 1):

In the login activity before going to main save the userid to shared pref

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//set value to pref
preferences.edit().putString("s_id", username.toString()).apply();
```

and get the data whenever you want

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
String id = preferences.getString("s_id", "default value");
```

Comment: How about, you have LoginActivity. Then it will go to MainActivity. after that there's 3 fragments, how they will get the current user id?

Comment: It crash the app.

Comment: add use this.getactivity, forgot it's a fragment

Comment: you can check my code here "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WGb1G4smHBXDugLkb5U9h2tV1IquiMAu?usp=sharing"